# How to use callbacks correctly to consume an API in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My problem is with consuming data from an API and modelling it effectivly before sending it over to the controller. I have a factory which gets user data from the API. The function that is giving me trouble in particular is the provideAllUserData function.

Here's my services.js

```
.factory('userDataService', function ($resource, settings){

        var dataService = {};

        var baseUrl = settings.baseUrl;

        dataService.getUsers = function () {
            return $resource(baseUrl + 'user').query();
        };

        dataService.getUserById = function (user) {
            return $resource(baseUrl + 'user/:id').get(
                {
                    id : user
                }
            )
        }

        dataService.provideAllUserData = function (user) {

            dataService.userData = {};
            var userData = dataService.userData;

            var updateUserData = function(callback){

                dataService.getUserById(user).$promise.then(function (res) {
                    var fetchUserData = res;
                    userData['id'] = fetchUserData.id;
                    userData['name'] = fetchUserData.name;
                    userData['quizzes'] = fetchUserData.quizzes;
                    dataService.userData = userData;
                    callback();

                });
            }

            var returnData = function() {
                //console.log(dataService.userData);
                console.log( dataService.userData)

            }
            updateUserData(returnData);
        }

    return dataService;

    })
```

Seems like it should be working, and if I console.log the callback, it returns the object that I want. However, when I try to log it in the controller, it returns an undefined.

Here's the relevent line from my controller.

```
console.log(userDataService.provideAllUserData(1));
```

Please let me know if I'm doing this completely wrong, or what you would do differently. I haven't used Angular for this before, so its kind of a learn-as-I-go situation.

Comment: you are not returning anything from your provideAllUserData method. That's why console.log giving you undefined

Comment: In angular you use promises, not callbacks. I wouldn't mix the two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You expect asynchronous code to behave in a synchronous way.

```
console.log(userDataService.provideAllUserData(1));
```

This wouldn't work. Asynchnonicity is contageous and it'll affect the calling code too.

First, drop that callback of yours and use only promises

```
dataService.provideAllUserData = function (user) {

    dataService.userData = {};
    var userData = dataService.userData;

    // "then" returns a promise. Meaning, multiple thens can be chained.
    return dataService.getUserById(user).then(function (res) {
        var fetchUserData = res;
        userData['id'] = fetchUserData.id;
        userData['name'] = fetchUserData.name;
        userData['quizzes'] = fetchUserData.quizzes;
        dataService.userData = userData;

    });
  }
```

Then, in calling code:

```
userDataService.provideAllUserData(1).then(function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: Thank you. That cleared things up. I didn't really properly how promises and then() worked.